# Can't get data with spaces into the database from Ajax POST request

Tags: php, ajax, encoding, joomla

I have a real simple form with a textbox and a button, and my goal is to have an asynchronous request (jQuery: $.ajax) send the text to the server (PHP/mysql a la Joomla) so that it can be added to a database table.

Here's the javascript that is sending the data from the client:

```
var value= $('#myvalue').val();

$.ajax( {
    type:       "POST",
    url:        "/administrator/index.php",
    data:       {   option: "com_mycomponent",
                    task:   "enterValue",
                    thevalue: value,
                    format: "raw"},
    dataType:   "text",
    success:    reportSavedValue
} );
```

The problem arises when the user enters text with a space in it.  The $_POST variable that I receive has all the spaces stripped out, so that if the user enters "**This string has spaces**", the server gets the value "**Thisstringhasspaces**".

I have been googling around, and have found lots of references that I need to use *encodeURIComponent*.  So I have tried it, but now the value that I get from $_POST is "**This20string20has20spaces**".

So it appears to be encoding it the way *I* would expect, only to have the percent signs stripped instead of the spaces, and leaving the hex numbers.

I'm really confused. It seems that this sort of question is asked and answered everywhere on the web, and everywhere *encodeURIComponent* is hailed as the silver bullet.  But apparently I'm fighting a different breed of lycanthrope.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is some filtering happening on the server. In my 400 years+ as a vampire I've never seen a string automagically have non-leading/trailing spaces stripped on the client (by jquery or whatever else)

Comment: Try to POST your data to a simple `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` page placed outside your Joomla.

Comment: what version of jquery? try setting processData = false; in the request. if it wont help -- it's server's fault.

Comment: Big thanks Karim79 and Cesar.  It was filtering on the server, and it was Joomla.  I was getting the value with JRequest::getCmd() which filters the value.  I thought I had checked with $_POST to make sure it behaved the same, but clearly I didn't pay close enough attention when I was verifying.  Formal answer below for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there was extra filtering I didn't realize I was performing.  Because this was all running through Joomla, I was using `JRequest::getCmd('thevalue')` instead of `$_POST['theValue]`.  This function, it turns out, filters out all those troublesome characters, like '%'.

So the final solution is to use *encodeURIComponent* on the client, as is unanimously suggested on the web:

```
var value = encodeURIComponent($('#myvalue').val());
```

And on the server, to trade `getCmd()` for `getVar()` which allows more control over the filtering, in combination with `urldecode()`:

```
$value = urldecode(JRequest::getvar('thevalue', JREQUEST_ALLOWHTML));
```

Again, big thanks to Karim79 and Cesar. I dub thee Harker and Helsing -- my heroes for the day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could I trouble you to try this, please?

```
var value = escape($('#myvalue').val());
```

Comment: Sure thing.  I tried it and it has the same result as var value = encodeURIComponent($('#myvalue').val()); -- the server picks up a value with '20' in place of all the spaces.